# Python XML remove elements if a child is not in it

Tags: python, xml

I have the following xml - "file.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<data>
    -<dataset>
         <ID>001</ID>
         <A>5</A>
         <B>2</B>
         <C>1</C>
    </dataset>
    -<dataset>
         <ID>002</ID>
         <A>6</A>
         <B>4</B>
         <C>2</C>
    </dataset>
    -<dataset>
         <ID>003</ID>
         <A>3</A>
    </dataset>  
    -<dataset>
         <ID>004</ID>
         <A>2</A>
         <C>5</C>
    </dataset>    
</data>
```

I want to keep all elements with children A and B. Child C doesn't matter at all. My approach is to delete those elements without child A or B. Say, missing of either A or B will trigger the deletion of that element.

Here is my code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()   


for element in root.findall('.//dataset'):
  if element.tag != 'A' and element.tag != 'B':
     root.remove(element)
```

This doesn't seem to be working.

Desired output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
-<data>
    -<dataset>
         <ID>001</ID>
         <A>5</A>
         <B>2</B>
         <C>1</C>
    </dataset>
    -<dataset>
         <ID>002</ID>
         <A>6</A>
         <B>4</B>
         <C>2</C>
    </dataset> 
</data>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot() 

#Get a list of the parent elements 'dataset' that have both element 'A' and 'B'
both =[]
for i in tree.findall(".//dataset/A/.."):
    if i in tree.findall(".//dataset/B/.."):
        both.append(i)
#Remove elements that are not in the above list 
for i in root:
    if i not in both:
        root.remove(i)
```